# xmlsocket flex and mac address

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, networking, air

For classroom, how do I actually able to remotely control 100's PC from a master application? 
Like control the student who also using Flex application is possble with XMLsocket?

I found some software use Mac address which allow the master application to access but I don't know what is need to build. Need guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also consider the peer-2-peer route, its probably the quickest and easiest way to get up and running. Apart from all the Adobe documentation, take a look at the HydraP2P library. It is very much beta quality, and the Command package doesn't make a lot of sense (AMF deserializing should be handled in the usual manner), but it should give you a headstart. A couple of Adobe evangelists have blogs that contain examples.

If you want to stick with a client/server model, with Air you can very easily create a socket server, there's an article here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/creating_socket_server.html

Comment: I seen this but will this work? The clients must know the server IP address?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in more then a couple of ways
1. XMLSocket - activate a function on the client's machines
2. Flash Media server - working with invoking methods inside the client's code.
3. BlazeDS - consumer producer

you have more, you can simply select the one suits you and just roll with it.

Comment: We don't allow server to be install in schools.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out the group features in [Adobe Cirrus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/cirrus/). If you are all on the same LAN, you don't need a server.

Comment: Cannot be use for commercial product.